# Unable to send TCP from Azure VM to GCP VM

Tags: site-to-site-vpn, azure-networking, gcp

I have setup a Ubuntu VM in Azure within a subnet 10.0.0.0/24 within a VNet's address space 10.0.0.0/16. Next I setup a Virtual Network Gateway with a tunnel to GCP vnet. I have an internal load balancer in GCP routing the traffic to a VM hosting a service listening on port 5000.

The tunnel is successfully connected. I have setup NSG to allow outgoing TCP via port 5000.

Network Watcher says TCP from my Azure VM's internal IP is able to make it to GCP Load Balancer's Frontend IP.

However I am unable to send text via netcat

`$echo -n -e "myfile.txt" | nc <IP ADDRESS OF GCP Load Balancer> 5000`

The above times out.

Questions:

1. How do I check that traffic from Azure VM is flowing thru the tunnel?
2. Am I missing any configuration?
3. How does a packet travelling thru the tunnel from Azure know to route itself to the load balancer? Is this automatic because I am using the IP of the GCP load balancer?

Comment: What kind of tunnel? How is the tunnel configured? I think you should include a network diagram with relevant adresses and configuration.